# How to structure messages between a web server and a job server

Tags: message-queue

For the SaaS infrastructure I'm building, we need to send transactional emails and run other long-running tasks on a separate job server. I can communicate via a queue, such as AWS' SQS or via a database table.

But what exactly should I send from the web server to the worker server via the queue mechanism?

- Should I send JSON text that has the entire email?
- Or should I send a request to send an email called "foobar" with parameters a, b, and c?
- Or something else?

Answer (score 3):

Choice B is superior. Enqueue a job by sending a
`Foobar(a, b, c)` message to the long-running job
queue. Do not pre-format the message in your web
server code. Sending job parameters is better for
both software engineering and practical site
performance/reliability reasons.

#### TL;DR Explanation

There are two key reasons: First, modularity. Sending notification messages
isn't a web serving function. Decoupling it is a cleaner, more modular design. A
separate back-end process for handling `Foobar` and similar long-running jobs
will enjoy the simplicity, maintainability, and other benefits that modularity
and separation of concerns bring.

An even more urgent, practical, frequently-unappreciated motivation: You do
**not** want to do any more work than necessary in your web serving code. Doing
so can cause you *major* performance and site reliability problems.

It seems incredible in a multi-core, multi-threaded, multi-GB age that resources
would be meaningfully constrained in your web server. Performance should not be
a problem, and failure because of resource exhaustion? It seems laughable. But
consider:

- Most web sites now run on cloud resources. Hosting operators (whether Amazon,
  Heroku, Digital Ocean, or your own IT shop) use virtualization, throttling,
  and quotas to aggressively pack as many customers and workloads as possible
  onto each physical server. They similarly multiplex and control memory,
  storage, network bandwidth, and other resources. They have become exceedingly
  efficient at it.

  However powerful your server was when it left the factory, your workload gets
  only a sliver of it--and its key system resources like CPU cache and physical
  memory are already well-taxed handling other apps and workloads than yours. It
  may seem like you "own the place," but that's the virtualization illusion.
  Rarely is it so. Hosting operators aren't terribly generous with resources.
  Their pricing tiers are often directly tied to how many worker processes,
  CPU-minutes, GB RAM, GB storage, etc. you get. They have little incentive to
  be generous or flexible. So typical web-serving resources are *much* more
  tightly constrained than you might imagine.
- Yet web servers are doing quasi real-time processing of network requests. They
  already have much to do, such as making requests on a DBMS, other shared
  middleware, storage, and remote servers, then filling out content templates to
  return to the user. They have to do that under tight latency constraints. If
  you have any kind of traffic volume whatsoever, each web-serving thread or
  process needs to complete many, many such requests per second. Especially
  long-running web workers (say, because they took extra time to access a slow
  API or to format an email message) can timeout. On some systems (e.g. Heroku),
  the timeout of one web worker kicks off a longish recovery process that, under
  load, can lead to other web requests being delayed and possibly timed out. Now
  you have the possibility of cascading failure.

  Even if you have light volume, web traffic is inherently burst-y. Have one of
  your links mentioned on a popular tweet or post and traffic soars
  instantaneously. Even "light duty" sites are on a much tighter timeline than
  you probably think, at least during burst moments.

  Let's say you can handle 50 concurrent requests. Maybe that seems "way more
  than enough!" because you generally get no more than 5 concurrent requests,
  "on average." Everything's golden, right? No. Even if your typical request
  count is `4, 2, 0, 10, 4`, in a bursty moment you might get a few peak seconds
  of the day with a request sequence like: `21, 47, 37, 65, 31, 28`. If you're
  doing more work than you have to on those requests, you're at risk on the 47,
  doubly at risk on the 47,37 one-two, and in mortal danger at 65.

  These are exactly the kind of burst patterns I pull out of logs. "But that
  can't be! Our site isn't that heavily loaded!" No, it's not. 86,381 seconds of
  each day, it's great. But those other 19 seconds, when by chance and
  happenstance you take >10x the average request load for a few seconds? You're at risk of a rolling
  disaster. If your web workers are efficient and complete their tasks quickly,
  queuing may save you. But if they run long and can't catch up, *uh oh*.
  You max out your worker pool (whether processes, threads, or event
  slots), start to generate timeouts and failures. Users and API callers get
  impatient and start requesting refreshes. In this process, the first
  failures/timeouts begin to cascade, causing subsequent ones. Suddenly your
  site is unresponsive, then essentially offline, then needs a hard reboot
  because it's exceeded some "maximum error threshold."  Now your site's offline,
  not serving users or taking revenue. *Ouch.* You only a second or two of
  fumbling for the whole thing to topple. 19 over-peak seconds a day isn't a
  lot...but it's more than enough to see 5 or 10 failure clusters and possible
  downtime events per day, with a handful of them coming during your peak hours.
  A small number of over-max events can wreak havoc. And in practice, they do.

  Worse, this is a transient problem, often very hard to debug ("We have plenty
  of resources! It can't be that!"), not easily proven (the 19 bad seconds
  constitute just 0.02% of the day, have to be found among millions of log
  records, and are not clearly marked "hey, problem is here!!"),
  and are worst at peak times
  when management is most concerned about the site. Everyone's angry and
  frustrated with the downage. Yet your management--even if otherwise
  technically adept--may not understand that you need more system resources,
  since "the site is usually lightly loaded!" and 19 overages / 86,400 seconds
  per day doesn't seem like that much. Devoting more resources costs more.
  Sometimes 2x or 3x more, because they thought everything'd be great on the
  "small" tier, when what was needed for truly reliable operation was the
  "large" instance size--and two of them. Even if you can get their assent, with
  some hosts, it is flat-out impossible to buy more CPU or memory for either
  love or money.

  This is the nightmare scenario. Does it happen every time? No. But it does
  happen--and when it does, it's *ugly*. Younger me would have been skeptical
  that it could happen, or that adding a few more tasks to web serving would
  make any practical difference. Sadder but wiser me knows better. Having been
  called in as a DevOps engineer to fix sites that are slumping or falling down,
  often at the worst possible times and often for no clear reason, many of them
  turned out to be web worker exhaustion or timeouts leading to cascading
  failure. It can be Python and Django, Ruby on Rails, or PHP and WordPress.
  I've seen no language, framework, or concurrency architecture that's
  inherently immune. It's a composite failure that occurs when you combine
  long-running web requests, strongly virtualized and quota-limited web hosts,
  and the economics of tiered pricing--in other words, the modern outsourced
  cloud environment. It can be addressed, but it's painful to do so after the
  fact.

So if you expect any scale of web traffic at all, web workers should seen as
quasi real-time request handlers. That means make them crisp and efficient.
Not "throw anything at them" general-purpose jobs. Thus, they should emit short
back-end requests, not pre-format them. It's also better modular design.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, it would be better if you could send the data in the form of strongly-typed business entity. On the worker server, you would have the benefit of manipulating the data with the help of intellisense in the IDE. You can easily write the code to formulate the email message with the help of business entity.

And try to send the request in the fire & forget mode and expect no response from the worker server. For instance, in the Microsoft WCF one-way communication data contracts can we used to address such needs.

If your message text size is small, then JSON would be good enough.